# How to throw syntax error for the object intersection type?

Tags: typescript

- TypeScript 3.2.2
- There are two types which have different properties: `A` and `B`.
- I want to accept `A` or `B`, but want to throw an error on [the intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of the two.

For example:

```
type A = { a: number }
type B = { b: number }

var a: A = { a: 1, b: 1 }     //← Property 'b' is invalid. Fine.
var b: B = { a: 1, b: 1 }     //← Property 'a' is invalid. Fine.
var c: A | B = { a: 1, b: 1 } //← I expected to be an error because this value is
                              //  compatible with neither A nor B, but allowed.
var d: A & B = { a: 1, b: 1 } //← OK because this is the intersection type.
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Definition%0D%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20%7B%20b%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20a%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%201%20%7D%0D%0Avar%20b%3A%20B%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%201%20%7D%0D%0Avar%20c%3A%20A%20%7C%20B%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%201%20%7D%20%2F%2F%E2%86%90%20I%20expected%20to%20be%20an%20error%20because%20this%20value%20is%20compatible%20with%20neither%20A%20nor%20B.%0D%0Avar%20d%3A%20A%20%26%20B%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%201%20%7D%0D%0A)

I expected the `A | B` to be one I want, but it was not.

How can I accept `A` or `B`, but not `A & B`?

Comment: Did I catch it wrong? "I expected the A | B to be one I want, but it was not." Wasn't it the `A&B`?

Comment: I want to throw an error if the value is `A&B`, and want to accept only either `A` or `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unions in TypeScript are inclusive, not exclusive.  You can sort of build exclusive unions like this:

```
type ProhibitKeys<K extends keyof any> = { [P in K]?: never }
type Xor<T, U> = (T & ProhibitKeys<Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>>) |
  (U & ProhibitKeys<Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>);

type A = { a: number }
type B = { b: number }
var a: Xor<A, B> = { a: 1 }; // okay
var b: Xor<A, B> = { b: 1 }; // okay
var c: Xor<A, B> = { a: 1, b: 1 }; // error, 
// {a: number, b: number} not assignable to Xor<A, B>
```